# OpenGL GLSL shader issue

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I am having an issue with my glsl shader i´ve made. The issue is that when I am calling glCreateShader(type)-(Which is in the beginning of compileShader method,  and where the type is either fragment shader or vertex shader (I've tried both) it returns 0, and I have also remade the shaders so they are very basic in case the shader code was wrong, but that did not help.

In my onSurfaceCreated method, I have the following code in the end:

```
    String vertexShaderSource = readTextFileFromResource(this.context, R.raw.vertex_shader);
    String fragmentShaderSource = readTextFileFromResource(this.context, R.raw.fragment_shader);

    shaderProgram = buildProgram(vertexShaderSource, fragmentShaderSource);
```

The method for reading a file:

```
public String readTextFileFromResource(Context context, int resourceId)
{
    StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        String nextLine;

        while((nextLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            body.append(nextLine);
            body.append('\n');
        }

    }catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not open resource: " +resourceId, ioe);
    }catch (Resources.NotFoundException nfe)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Resource not found: " + resourceId, nfe);
    }

    return body.toString();
}
```

The buildProgram code is first compiling shaders:

```
int fragmentShader = compileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource);
int vertexShader = compileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
```

The fragment and vertex shaders:

```
void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = gl_Vertex;
}
```

Is there anything uncertain or more information you need please let me know, at the moment the shader get stuck at creation of shader.

Edit: Code added:

```
private int compileShader(int type, String shaderCode)
{
    int shaderHandle = glCreateShader(type);
    if(shaderHandle != 0)
    {
        // Pass the shader source
        glShaderSource(shaderHandle, shaderCode);
        // ^Upload our shader source code into the shader

        // Compile shader
        glCompileShader(shaderHandle);

        // Check compilation status
        final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
        glGetShaderiv(shaderHandle, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);
        if(compileStatus[0] == 0)
        {
            glDeleteShader(shaderHandle);
            shaderHandle = 0;
            Log.d(TAG, "Compilation of shader failed");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Compilation of shader successful");
        }
    }
    if(shaderHandle == 0)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Context: "+this.context);
        throw new RuntimeException("Error creating shader");
    }

    return shaderHandle;
}


public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);

    String vertexShaderSource = readTextFileFromResource(this.context, R.raw.vertex_shader);
    String fragmentShaderSource = readTextFileFromResource(this.context, R.raw.fragment_shader);

    shaderProgram = buildProgram(vertexShaderSource, fragmentShaderSource);

}
```

Comment: Make sure you have a valid GL context when trying to call GL functions.

Comment: The vertex shader looks invalid, OpenGL ES does not have a predefined `gl_Vertex` variable. But in any case, you're not showing the code where you say the error occurs, so there's no way to tell what exactly goes wrong. Is it really `glCreateShader()` returning 0, or is it the shader compilation failing?

Comment: @RetoKoradi The error occurred in the methods ive shared, I have made checks to see if the variable from glCreateShader() is 0 or not, and if 0, throw an RunTimeException which is where the error shows. I also shows where I am trying to compile the shaders. About the vertex shader, I did try and look up some basic shaders and that was one of them, but if it is wrong how would I correct it ?

Comment: @sandmaster: You say the error occurs in `compileShader` but you have _not_ pasted its code. If `glCreateShader` returns 0, you most likely don't have a valid GL context at this point in time (cwhich is current to the calling thread). Another option would by a `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` situation, but the latter is very unlikely.

Comment: @derhass Added the missing things, hopefully it helps.

Comment: I now have a different program made in OpenGL 2 and that is working as expected, but when I am trying to move it over to a program which has been using Open GL 1 it doesn't seem to work at all. Can it have anything to do with that ? Ive also tried using the function glSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2); but then the app is spamming: called unimplemented OpenGL ES API